# Building a buck converter using CMOS 555 with mosfet driver

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, 555, mosfet-driver

Can I use [ICM7555](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/ICM7555.pdf) IC to generate 300 KHz PWM signal and feed that PWM to [IRL2104](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2104-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c7c1c31671) mosfet driver to build a non-isolated DC to DC buck converter?

I'm asking this question because I couldn't find any decent buck converter design using CMOS 555 timer that have voltage feedback and a mosfet driver, thought to myself maybe it is not possible or at least the idea may have fundamental problems.

<sup>I've very little knowledge about switching power supplies, go easy on me.</sup>

Comment: Is there a reason to use a 555 for this? Chips specifically meant for building buck converters exist, integrated with features that need to be externally implemented with separate components.

Comment: guess one can use a 555 for a buck converter, but why? better IC's are not really more expensive and with higher frequ. your inductance gets smaller, smaller ripple,... so its more a lecture for trainees than a practical consideration,...

Comment: Here's the generic answer: *I couldn't find any decent buck converter design using CMOS 555*

Comment: A 555 seems to be the wrong choice here – either you're building something open-loop, in which case you'll have no feedback and no real regulation, or you're building something closed loop, and then your 555 becomes nothing but an inelegant method to solve a small subproblem of the overal converter problem; you'd simply not do that, but use one of the many (cheap!) existing buck converter / controller ICs. In your case, the low-power IRL2104 implies that even the very classic ICs will do that at a much lower cost, probability of failure, complexity.

Comment: In other words the question "how to build a buck converter with a 555" is as far as I can see "use the 555 as decoration only, and design a proper buck converter without it", just as "how do I design an airplane with chocolate pudding" is "use the pudding elsewhere and design the aircraft without pudding. Pudding doesn't help when building aircraft."

Comment: Also, fully aware that you might be subject to availability restrictions, but last time I checked a classic MC34063 (or clone thereof) isn't any more high-tech than a CMOS 555.

Comment: No because the 555 is built to generate a stable frequency while a buck converter needs a variable frequency. Without adapting the frequency, the output voltage will fluctuate with the load.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks, turn that into an answer if you can please.

Comment: @Andyaka Got it.

Comment: @Fredled I thought it is done by changing the duty cycle not frequency...

Comment: @Fredled: There's plenty of fixed-frequency buck converters out there, and a 555 can be easily made into a variable-frequency device by changing the voltage on the threshold pin or by adding external circuitry -- so, wrong on both counts.

Comment: @TimWescott "by changing the voltage' and 'by adding external circuitry" are redundant statements. And prove my point: You can't use the 555 because you will need additional circuitry. Of course with additional circuitry anything can work.

Comment: "No because ... a buck converter needs variable frequency".  That sure sounds like it was your point, and it's refuted by thousands of buck converters out there.

Comment: @TimWescott They need either variable frequency or variable duty cycle. Either case you need to modify a parameter to control the output. And it's not convenient with a 555.

Comment: @Fredled Absolutely.  That's my point.  When you said that they needed variable frequency, that statement was misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 555 seems to be the wrong choice here – either you're building something open-loop, in which case you'll have no feedback and no real regulation, or you're building something closed loop, and then your 555 becomes nothing but an inelegant method to solve a small subproblem of the overal converter problem; you'd simply not do that.

Instead, you'd use one of the many (cheap!) existing buck converter / controller ICs. In your case, the low-power IRL2104 implies that even the very classic ICs will do that at a much lower cost, probability of failure, complexity.

In other words the question "*how to build a buck converter with a 555*" is as far as I can see answered by  "*use the 555 as decoration only, and design a proper buck converter without it*", just as "*how do I design an airplane with chocolate pudding*" with "*use the pudding elsewhere and design the aircraft without pudding. Pudding doesn't help when building aircraft.*"

Also, fully aware that you might be subject to availability restrictions, but last time I checked a classic MC34063 (or clone thereof) isn't any more high-tech than a CMOS 555.

To be absolutely clear: if you can buy more modern ICs, don't buy the MC34063. It's really ancient (1983), and voltage converters have progressed a lot in the last four decades; buy something modern, which will have better ripple and regulation, higher efficiency and need a smaller inductor. Using a low-tech MC34063 is just still better than trying to shoe-horn a 555 into the job of a converter controller.

Comment: But - if you live somewhere where you *can* get up to date components, the MC34063 probably only belongs in a nostalgia project.

Comment: Fully agreed. but aside from the cheapness, point was: by 1983, the MC34063 [was available](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78116/mc34063-switching-regulator-ic-when-was-it-introduced); I can't find out whether that predates the CMOS ICM7555, but it's about as high-tech as being able to buy sliced bags in plastic bags and should be as available.

Comment: Oh, absolutely.  Both of those chips are old enough to buy alcohol, twice over.  I just don't want someone stumbling across your answer and thinking that the MC34063 should be their go-to chip.

Comment: @TimWescott oh! Yes. Added a closing paragraph. thanks!